# Vonage/Nexmo - PHP SDK - How to send MMS?

Tags: php, mms, vonage, outbound

I would like to send MMS using PHP SDK. There is no proper documentation on how to send it.

Any help in this regard highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See on Voange Developer: [Click here](https://developer.vonage.com/en/messages/code-snippets/mms/send-mms)

This is a simple example how to use the api:

```
<?php

use Nexmo\Client;

$client = new Client(new Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Basic('API_KEY', 'API_SECRET'));

$sended_message = $client->message()->send([
    'to' => 'PHONE_NUMBER_TO',
    'from' => 'PHONE_NUMBER_FROM',
    'type' => 'mms',
    'media' => ['https://www.xxx.xxx/test.jpg'],
    'message' => 'example mms'
]);

print_r($sended_message);
```

Comment: I use Vonage\Client. Looks like this is not available.